# AWS Lambda Flask file upload issue

Tags: python-3.x, aws-lambda, flask-restful

Im looking at a super strange issue when uploading files, using boto3 and Flask.
If I upload a standard txt file, all is fine and dandy, but if any other file type, like zip, exe or pdf, the files is changed. IE. the file size, type and hash is different the the original file.

Here as an example I've uploaded Putty.exe.
Output :

```
{
"file": "putty.exe",
"message": "success",
"path": "/tmp/putty.exe",
"s3": "",
"sha1": "9b36616702410e029857bc2dd3b7f2f0d7db187a",
"sha256": "5e3dfdce6cefb28f3cafe506a657a5ff44e199c3c821cbd587906f5aea435d10",
"size": "1.7 MB",
"type": "MS-DOS executable"
}
```

The correct SHA-1 of putty is 73016558c8353509b15cd757063816369e9abfa7

And when testing by flask app locally the file size and info is correct.

output from local test.

```
{
"file": "putty.exe",
"message": "success",
"path": "/tmp/putty.exe",
"s3": "",
"sha1": "73016558c8353509b15cd757063816369e9abfa7",
"sha256": "736330aaa3a4683d3cc866153510763351a60062a236d22b12f4fe0f10853582",
"size": "1.0 MB",
"type": "PE32 executable (GUI) Intel 80386, for MS Windows"
}
```

Here is my current testing code.

```
import os
import boto3
import yara
import tempfile
import hashlib
import pefile
import uuid
import magic
from flask import Flask, request, redirect, send_file, url_for, jsonify
from werkzeug.utils import secure_filename

app = Flask(__name__)
bucket_name = "<Bucket name>"

# File size
def convert_bytes(num):
    """
    this function will convert bytes to MB.... GB... etc
    """
    for x in ['bytes', 'KB', 'MB', 'GB', 'TB']:
        if num < 1024.0:
            return "%3.1f %s" % (num, x)
        num /= 1024.0

def file_size(file_path):
    """
    this function will return the file size
    """
    if os.path.isfile(file_path):
        file_info = os.stat(file_path)
        return convert_bytes(file_info.st_size)

def get_hash(filename):
    fh = open(filename, 'rb')
    m = hashlib.md5()
    s = hashlib.sha1()
    s256 = hashlib.sha256()
    s512 = hashlib.sha512()
    while True:
        data = fh.read(8192)
        if not data:
                break

        m.update(data)
        s.update(data)
        s256.update(data)
        s512.update(data)

    md5  = m.hexdigest()
    sha1 = s.hexdigest()
    sha256 = s256.hexdigest()
    sha512 = s512.hexdigest()

    return md5,sha1,sha256,sha512



def process_file(file):
    s3_resource = boto3.resource('s3')
    file_path = os.path.join(tempfile.gettempdir(),file)
    s3_resource.Bucket(bucket_name).download_file(file,file_path)
    return True

@app.route("/")
def main():
    return  '{"messasge" : "Hello world"}'

@app.route("/realtimescan", methods=['POST'])
def realtimescan():
    filetype = ""
    tempdirectory = tempfile.gettempdir()
    file = request.files['file']
    content_type = request.mimetype
    if file:
        filename = secure_filename(file.filename)
        s3_resource = boto3.resource('s3')
        my_bucket = s3_resource.Bucket(bucket_name)
        my_bucket.Object(filename).put(Body=file.file)
        #boto3.client('s3').put_object(Bucket=bucket_name, Key=filename, Body=file)
        tmp_path = os.path.join(tempdirectory, filename)

        if process_file(filename):
            md5, sha1, sha256, sha512 = get_hash(tmp_path)
            try:
                filetype = str(magic.from_file(tmp_path, mime=False))
            except:
                filetype = "na"

            ret = ({"message" : "success",
                "file" : filename,
                "path" : tmp_path,
                "size" : file_size(tmp_path),
                "type" : filetype,
                "sha256" : sha256,
                "sha1" : sha1,
                "s3" : ""
            })
        else:
            ret = ({"message" : "error"})
        return ret

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

I have zero clue what the issue is.
Also, if there are a better way to process the file in memory rather then saving to /tmp, tips & tricks are more than welcome.

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

Ok turned out that one needs to set Binary Media Types under API Gateway settings to `*/*` to accept binary file types.